# Apply sieve of Eratosthenes and longest common subsequent algorithms to pandas dataframe to remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove duplicates from the dataframe. I consider 2 rows as duplicates if 30 characters in `'summary'` column match. 
So I have Longest Common Subsequent function:

```
def lcs(X, Y, th=30): 
    '''X, Y- strings
    th-threshold '''
    m=len(X)
    n=len(Y)
    if m<th or n<th:
        if X==Y:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    LCSuff = [[0 for k in range(n+1)] for l in range(m+1)] 
    
    result = 0
    
  
    for i in range(m + 1): 
        for j in range(n + 1): 
            if (i == 0 or j == 0): 
                LCSuff[i][j] = 0
            elif (X[i-1] == Y[j-1]): 
                LCSuff[i][j] = LCSuff[i-1][j-1] + 1
                result = max(result, LCSuff[i][j]) 
                if result>=th:
                    return True
            else: 
                LCSuff[i][j] = 0
    return False
```

I have another function to remove duplicates using `lcs()` function above:

```
def remove_duplicates(dataframe, th=30):
    df=dataframe.copy()
    #create a new empty DataFrame
    distinct=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    distinc=distinct.append(df.loc[0])

    while len(df)>0:
        #add a new row to distinct df
        distinct=distinct.append(df.loc[0],  ignore_index=True)

        text=df.loc[0,'summary']    
        indicies=[]
        for i in range(len(df)):
            text2=df.loc[i, 'summary']
            if  lcs(text, text2, th):
                indicies.append(i)
        
        df=df.drop(indicies)
        df=df.reset_index(drop=True)  

    return distinct
```

This function can be tested with the following sample data, where only 10 character matching is considered:

```
d={'summary':['OldText:theTextOld', 'NewText:theTextNew', 'someText', 'someTextOther', 'someOtherT:theTextNew', 'someText']}
data=pd.DataFrame(d)
remove_duplicates(data, 10)
```

It takes almost an hour to run this function for about 3000-rows dataframe. How can I improve the code with pandas `apply()` function?

Comment: Have you profiled the code? Do you know *why* it's slow?

Comment: What does the Sieve of Erahosthenes have to do with removing duplicates?

Comment: You should also add a small, representative dataset with fake data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Obviously because I use a while loop which is not recommended when working with pandas. I know that  pandas' apply() function has a better speed. I just don't know how to use it correctly.

Comment: Your definition of duplicate isn't transitive. You could have `row i` be a "duplicate" of `row j` and `row j` be a duplicate of `row k` but `row i` *not* be a duplicate of `row k`

Comment: @JohnColeman I just used the logic of removing rows like this algorithm removes non-prime numbers.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am aware about  this non-transitive problem. However, I thought this could be a way to get rid of duplicates. If you have any suggestion on how to remove duplicates that have matching 30 characters, please advise.

Comment: @Julia I have added a sample dataset

Comment: What exactly are your matching rules for characters?  It doesn't look like you are looking at character position, but duplicates?  What is the match count between the words "doodad" and "did"?  Is it 6 matches or 1 count?

Comment: @AirSquid As you see from `lcs()` function it  returns True if `th` number of consecutive characters match. So in your example it's just 1

Comment: I'm not sure what you already have is working.  using your sample data and th=4 doesn't seem to produce an accurately reduced df.  And between the "duplicates" you seem to not care which one gets nuked?  Also... you realize that "matching" like this is not transitive, so you might get odd results.  If A -> B and B->C, that doesn't mean A->C so if you nuke "B" then then "C" survives in many cases.

Comment: @AirSquid I omitted ‘th’ in the second function by mistake. I have corrected that. It should work now. As to which row should be kept, I don’t have any specified rule. And my question is how to make this work faster.

Answer (score 0):

2 things can be done to change the structure...  You won't be able to use `apply()` on this because you are comparing each element with every other.

1. rewrite your LCS function a bit.  It is not necessary to have a double-nested loop to find sequences of duplicates.  Just walk the length of the shorter word and make comparisons, keep track of the max, etc.  That will speed up that portion, but that is not likely your biggest slowdown...
2. in your function to remove dupes, you are doing a bunch of appends/drops inside of a loop on a data frame, which is really slow.  You should mark everything once and then do one selection of whatever is not marked.  To do that, I would extract the series `summary` and run that through your dupe finder and make a corollary list of boolean "marks" where you want to delete things.  Append that series to the data frame and use it to delete all the dupes at once.

This should be quite quick on a frame of only ~3000 words.